# Push notifications in iOS11 (Xcode 9 swift 4)

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ios11, swift4.1

How can I get push notifications on iOS11 in the background? I tried this and never succeeded.

Why when in the foreground does a notification appear while in the background it doesn't appear? Is there something missing with my source code or settings in the info.plist?

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID

struct DataNotif: Codable {
    var title: String?
    var body: String?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case body
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    static var DEVICE_ID = String()
    var msg_body = ""
    var msg_title = ""
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (granted, error) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print("I received the following error: \(error!)")
                }else if (granted) {
                    print ("Authorization was granted!")
                }else{
                    print ("Authorization was not granted. :(")
                }
            }
            
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        return true
    }
    
    func connectToFcm() {
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    }
 
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        
        if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            AppDelegate.DEVICE_ID = refreshedToken
            print("*********")
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
            print("*********")
        }else{
            print("Can't get token device")
        }
        
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications with error: \(error)")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        print(userInfo)
        
        guard let data: [String: Any] = userInfo as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }
        
        let listData = data["notification"] as! String
        let jsonData = listData.data(using: .utf8)
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dataJson = try decoder.decode(DataNotif.self, from: jsonData!)
            
            msg_body = dataJson.body!
            msg_title = dataJson.title!
            
            createNotification(title: msg_title, body: msg_body)
            
        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
        
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let notification = response.notification.request.content.body
        
        print(notification)
        
        completionHandler()
        
    }
    
    // messaging
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        
        if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            AppDelegate.DEVICE_ID = token
            print("*********")
            print("Token Instance: \(token)")
            print("*********")
        }
 
        connectToFcm()
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
        
        guard let data: [String: Any] = remoteMessage.appData as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }
        
        print(data)
        
        let listData = data["notification"] as! String
        let jsonData = listData.data(using: .utf8)
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dataJson = try decoder.decode(DataNotif.self, from: jsonData!)
            
            msg_body = dataJson.body!
            msg_title = dataJson.title!
            
            createNotification(title: msg_title, body: msg_body)
            
        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
        
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
 
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        connectToFcm()
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        if let vc = window?.rootViewController as? HomeController {
            vc.scheduleNotification()
        }
        
        completionHandler(.newData)
        
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
        print("Disconnect FCM")
    }
 
    func createNotification(title: String, body: String) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: title, arguments: nil)
        content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: body, arguments: nil)
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.badge = NSNumber(integerLiteral: UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: title, content: content, trigger: nil)
        
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request)
    }
    
}
```

[This sample post notification in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFjKz.png)

Comment: what's inside vc.scheduleNotification()?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, have you found any solution?